# lxml.html and Unicode: Extract Links

Tags: python, html, unicode, utf-8, lxml

The code below extracts links from a web page and shows them in a browser. With a lot of UTF-8 encoded webpages this works great. But the French Wikipedia page [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/États_unis](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tats_unis) for example produces an error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n'
print '''<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show Links</title>
</head>
<body>'''

import urllib2, lxml.html as lh

def load_page(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; testbot/0.1)'}
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        page = response.read()
        return page
    except:
        print '<b>Couldn\'t load:', url, '</b><br>'
        return None

def show_links(page):
    tree = lh.fromstring(page)
    for node in tree.xpath('//a'):
        if 'href' in node.attrib:
            url = node.attrib['href']
            if '#' in url:
                url=url.split('#')[0]
            if '@' not in url and 'javascript' not in url:
                if node.text:
                    linktext = node.text
                else:
                    linktext = '-'
                print '<a href="%s">%s</a><br>' % (url, linktext.encode('utf-8'))

page = load_page('http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tats_unis')
show_links(page)

print '''
</body>
</html>
'''
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***\question.py", line 42, in <module>
    show_links(page)
  File "C:\***\question.py", line 39, in show_links
    print '<a href="%s">%s</a><br>' % (url, linktext.encode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My system: Python 2.6 (Windows), lxml 2.3.3, Apache Server (to show the results)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add a line `print repr(linktext)` just before the failing line, and edit your question to show the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode `url` too.

The problem might be similar to:

```
>>> "%s%s" % (u"", "€ <-non-ascii char in a bytestring")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in
range(128)
```

But this works:

```
>>> "%s%s" % (u"".encode('utf-8'), "€ <-non-ascii char in a bytestring")
'\xe2\x82\xac <-non-ascii char in a bytestring'
```

The empty Unicode string forces the whole expression to be converted to Unicode. Therefore you see Unicode *Decode* Error.

In general it is a bad idea to mix Unicode and bytestrings. It might appear to be working but sooner or later it breaks. Convert text to Unicode as soon as you receive it, process it and then convert it to bytes for I/O.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>lxml returns bytestrings not unicode. It might be better to `decode` the bytestring to unicode using whatever encoding the page was served with, before encoding as utf-8.</strike>

If your text is *already* in utf-8, there is no need to do any encoding or decoding - just take that operation out.

However, if your linktext is of type `unicode` (as you say it is), then it is a unicode string (each element represents a unicode codepoint), and encoding as utf-8 should work perfectly well.

I suspect the problem is that your `url` string is *also* a unicode string, and it also needs to be encoded as utf-8 before being substituted into your bytestring.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! The Wikipedia page is encoded in utf-8. linktext.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8') gives me an error too. BTW: Why is linktext of <type 'unicode'>?

Comment: @renardvolant You have lost your third sentence. Anyway, try my suggestion; I think you will find that it resolves your problem.

Comment: @Marcin: Thank you too. I gave the "Accepted answer" to J.F. Sebastian because he was 2 min faster ;-)

Comment: @renardvolant Feel free to express your gratitude through the voting system.

Comment: @Marcin: My reputation score is below 15. So I can't upvote your answer. Another time!

Comment: @renardvolant I wasn't aware of that limitation. If you pass by, remember to vote up JFSebastian's answer also.